# Do the curvature and the normal curvature of a curve have a similar intuitive meaning?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, curvature

The *curvature* $\kappa$ of a curve $C$ at a point $P$ is defined as the reciprocal of the radius of curvature $\rho$ of $C$ at $P$. Conversely, the *normal curvature vector* of a curve $C$ lying on a surface $S$ at $P$, denoted by $\mathbf{k}_{n}$, is defined as the vector projection of the curvature vector $\mathbf{k}$ of the curve $C$ at $P$ onto the normal $\mathbf{N}$ of the surface $S$ at $P$; *i.e*,
$$
\mathbf{k}_{n}=(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{N}) \mathbf{N}
$$

And its magnitude, $\kappa_n=\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{N}$, is the *normal curvature* of $C$ at $P$.

I wonder what is the need to define this new type of curvature, $\kappa_n$, and what its geometrical meaning is. Does it have an intuitive meaning similar to that of the curvature $\kappa$, which can be understood as the reciprocal of the radius of the osculating circle to the curve at point $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the normal curvature is a characteristic of the *surface* and not of the particular curve. Any two curves with the same tangent direction at $P$ will have the same *normal* curvature at $P$, but will generally have wildly different curvatures.

You can recover the normal curvature in direction $v$ as (up to sign) the curvature of a particular curve — namely, the normal slice of the surface in direction $v$ (i.e., the intersection of the surface with the plane through $P$ spanned by the normal and $v$).

See section 2.2 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) for more details. Be warned, though, that I use $\mathbf N$ for the principal normal of a curve and $\mathbf n$ for the surface normal.

Comment: So, if we drew the osculating circle at the plane whose intersection with the surface gives the curve, the normal curvature would be the inverse of the radius of that circle?

Comment: Your general curve will not be plane section of the surface. But, *if* you consider the normal section, as I indicated, then, yes, the normal curvature (up to sign) will be the inverse of the radius of the osculating circle at $P$ of that plane curve.